# How can I reset the system from a guest account?

Tags: 16.04, reset

At my work they were throwing away computers so I saved a **Dell** laptop from the dumpster. I just have the computer and the charger.

It's pretty beat up, but works fine. On it is **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**. The previous user (probably my boss) didn't give me his password, and I'd probably prefer to delete his data anyways, but at the moment I can only login with a guest account.

I would like to reset the system from the guest account, or know what I can do to use the computer as the new user. I would prefer not to bother my boss because he might be worried that I would access his information.

Comment: best approach, erase the disk and install from scratch..., that way also you could choose a light desktop (xfce/lxde), install only the software that you want/need and customize it as you like, without hiting the wall of an already used system. Finally if you erase securely (shred) the disk, your boss will be happy.

Comment: @bistoco Thanks a lot! Could you provide a couple of steps on how to do this or links? As I said I'm totally new to the system and find it confusing

Comment: first you must erase securely the hard drive, to do this, you could use `shred` from a live cd, something like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15037/use-an-ubuntu-live-cd-to-securely-wipe-your-pcs-hard-drive/). It will take a while since it writes every bit more than once. Get back when you are done with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)
Once you change the password, Create a new account for yourself and erase the old one. I hope this helped and good luck on exploring Linux!